# Modificar nodo en C

Tags: c, funciones, algoritmos, lista

Tengo esta función para modificar un nodo, pero cuando la uso lo que hace es modificar el nodo que le pedí pero borra las demás.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que modifique y no borre los otros nodos?

```
_nodoActividades *modificarActividades(_nodoActividades *apuntador)
{
    char materia[20];
    char tipo[20];
    printf("\nQUE ACTIVIDAD DESEA MODIFICAR:  ");
    scanf("%s",materia);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nINDICO EL TIPO DE ACTIVIDAD: ");
    scanf("%s",tipo);
    fflush(stdin);

    if (!listaVaciaActividades(apuntador))
    {
        _nodoActividades *apuntadorAuxiliar;

        apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntador;

        while (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL)
        {           
            if (apuntadorAuxiliar != NULL && strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, materia) == 0)
            //(!verificarNombre(apuntador, materia) && !verificarTipo(apuntador, tipo)) //&& strcmp(apuntadorAuxiliar->tipoDeActividad, materia) == 0))
            {
                if(!verificarTipo(apuntador, tipo))
                {
                    char nombre[30];
                    char tipoDeActividad[30];
                    char diaDeLaSemana[20];
                    char horaDeIncio[10];
                    char horaDeFin[10];
                    char salon[10];


                    system("clear");
                    printf("\n----NUEVA ACTIVIDAD----\n");
                    printf("NOMBRE DE LA MATERIA: ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",nombre);
                    while(!validarLetras(nombre))
                    {
                        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
                        printf("\nNOMBRE: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%s",nombre);

                        /*while(!buscarMateria())*/
                    }
                    printf("TIPO DE ACTIVIDAD: ");
                    fflush(stdin);  
                    scanf("%s",tipoDeActividad);
                    while(!validarLetras(tipoDeActividad))
                    {
                        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS ");
                        printf("\nTIPO DE ACTIVIDAD: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%s",tipoDeActividad);
                    }
                    printf("DIA DE LA SEMANA: ");
                    fflush(stdin);  
                    scanf("%s",diaDeLaSemana);
                    while(!validarLetras(diaDeLaSemana))
                    {
                        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA LETRAS");
                        printf("\nDIA DE LA SEMANA: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%s",diaDeLaSemana);
                    }
                    printf("HORA DE INICIO:  ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",horaDeIncio);
                    while(!validarNumero(horaDeIncio))
                    {
                        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA NUMEROS");
                        printf("\nHORA DE INICIO: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%s",horaDeIncio);
                    }
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("HORA DE FIN:  ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",horaDeFin);
                    while(!validarNumero(horaDeFin))
                    {
                        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA NUMEROS");
                        printf("\nHORA DE FIN: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%s",horaDeFin);
                    }
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf("SALON:  ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",salon);
                    while(!validarNumero(salon))
                    {
                        printf("\nPOR FAVOR SOLO ESCRIBA NUMEROS");
                        printf("\nSALON: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%s",salon);
                    }
                    fflush(stdin);

                    strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->nombre, nombre);
                    strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->tipoDeActividad, tipoDeActividad);
                    strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->diaDeLaSemana, diaDeLaSemana);
                    strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->horaDeIncio, horaDeIncio);
                    strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->horaDeFin, horaDeFin);
                    strcpy(apuntadorAuxiliar->salon, salon);
                    apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = NULL;
                }
            }

        apuntadorAuxiliar = apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente;
        }
    printf("\nSU MATERIA FUE MODIFICADA EXITOSAMENTE");
    getchar();  
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nNO EXISTE ESA MATERIA CREADA");
        getchar();
    }

    return apuntador;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ponernos un [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Para poder reproducir con facilidad tu problema necesitamos algo más de código. Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He estado revisando tu código y en ningún momento borras ni modificas los datos anteriores (el `if` con los `strcmp` se encarga de ello).

Pero tienes un error al asignar `apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente = NULL;` ya que con eso estás haciendo que termine ahí la cadena de nodos, cuando eso no es cierto si previamente `apuntadorAuxiliar->siguiente` no valía `NULL`, provocando que, aparentemente, no haya más nodos más allá del que has modificado.

Debes quitar esa línea y debería funcionarte correctamente.